# Cascading Dropdown In PHP

Tags: php

I have two dropdown list in my page i.e Location and Employee.
What I want to do is that I want to filter the employee according to the location.
That is ,,, When I select location Delhi than all the employees at delhi location are came into employee dropdown.
Is it possible in PHP????
Please help me out

Comment: Please post your code relevant to your question. Also this definitely is possible with PHP, have you attempted anything or was this the first place you looked?

Comment: you have to use `ajax + php` for this. alone php can't do this.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar: If he is fine with a page reload, he can just do it with php? Of course it is nice to have AJAX do calls in the background; but I am just trying to keep his options open for him to decide.

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible using just PHP unless you are okay with a page refresh in between. There are many ways to do this in JavaScript, have you tried using JavaScript?

EDIT: There might be some complex way using CSS3 selectors, but even if there is I would not advise doing it.

Answer (score 0):

yes nothing is imposible. you can do it.. but you have to use scripting languages like ajax to accomplish that.. If you need more help please post your code....Yuo could find the answer here..

[Populating second drop down based on selection of first with value from first database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388038/populating-second-drop-down-based-on-selection-of-first-with-value-from-first-da)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible using php with ajax implementation.

Here's a good tutorial in which country, state, city example given. Hope this will help you.

http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/01/populate-triple-drop-down-list-change-options-value-from-database-using-ajax-and-php.html